# javascript counter - how to include more than one counter on the same page?

Tags: javascript, counter

Can someone please help me implement two javascript counters inside a single page?  I currently have the counter up and running but when I try to create a new div for another counter, the original counter disappears and only one counter is displayed.  This is my first post so please excuse any messed up formatting.  I would greatly appreciate any help, I'm quite new to javascript.  Thank you!

Here is my code:

```
<div id="counter"></div>
<div id="counter1"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
var START_DATE = new Date("July 27, 2010 13:30:00"); // put in the starting date here
var INTERVAL = 1; // in seconds
var INCREMENT = 2; // increase per tick
var START_VALUE = 9001; // initial value when it's the start date
var count = 0;

window.onload = function()
{
var msInterval = INTERVAL * 1000;
var now = new Date();
count = parseInt((now - START_DATE)/msInterval) * INCREMENT + START_VALUE;
document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = addCommas(count);
setInterval("count += INCREMENT; document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = 
addCommas(count);", msInterval);
}
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
var START_DATE = new Date("July 27, 2011 13:30:00"); // put in the starting date here
var INTERVAL = 1; // in seconds
var INCREMENT = 2; // increase per tick
var START_VALUE = 8001; // initial value when it's the start date
var count = 0;

window.onload = function()
{
var msInterval = INTERVAL * 1000;
var now = new Date();
count = parseInt((now - START_DATE)/msInterval) * INCREMENT + START_VALUE;
document.getElementById('counter1').innerHTML = addCommas(count);
setInterval("count += INCREMENT; document.getElementById('counter1').innerHTML =   
addCommas(count);", msInterval);
}
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
function addCommas(nStr)
{
nStr += '';
x = nStr.split('.');
x1 = x[0];
x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
while (rgx.test(x1)) {
    x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
}
return x1 + x2;
}
</script>
```

Comment: You can't just copy the code again. All those variables have the same name! At the very least, you need to define the second counter with different variable names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have two `window.onload` scripts, the last one will overwrite the first one.

Just reuse the same code and simply add the next counter to the next div.

```
window.onload = function()
{
    var msInterval = INTERVAL * 1000;
    var now = new Date();
    count = parseInt((now - START_DATE)/msInterval) * INCREMENT + START_VALUE;
    document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = addCommas(count);
    setInterval("count += INCREMENT; document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = addCommas(count);", msInterval);
    document.getElementById('counter1').innerHTML = addCommas(count);
    setInterval("document.getElementById('counter1').innerHTML =  addCommas(count);", msInterval);
}
```

EDIT: Increment count only once, otherwise the second counter is ahead of the first always

Comment: Thank you so much for providing an answer!  I was able to have both counters show up and it's wonderful.  Just one more question - Is it possible to have the two counters incrementing with separate values?  The two counters are both displaying the same exact numbers and I would love to have each counter with its own values and starting date.  Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: I think what you're looking for is a good tutorial in programming in general, in terms of Javascript these will help you, run through them, I know you will enjoy it

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn/javascript